# Typo3 update of ttnews produced blank pages in BE and FE and Install-Tool

Tags: php, typo3

Tried to update Typo3 4.2. According to Typo3 Documentation I had to update the extensions first. So I proceeded to update tt_news. The only possible update version was 6.0 so I did that. A blank FE, BE and a non existent Install Tool was the result. Did alter the localconf.php to display errors. 
This is what I got:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility' not found in /mnt/webe/e0/32/51675432/htdocs/typo3_grau_02/typo3conf/temp_CACHED_ps6a24_ext_localconf.php on line 1265
```

When I looked at line 1265 in the correct document there was only a copyright information to be found.

What can I do to have access to FE and BE again?

Answer (score 1):

If an extension uses the namespace classes of TYPO3 you cannot get that to work with TYPO3 4.2. Proceed your update. This error will not persist after your core is up to date.